# 'NSError' is not convertible to 'NSError?'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I just upgraded to Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2, and am in the process of updating syntaxes. In my project I use [TCBlobDownloadSwift](https://github.com/thibaultCha/TCBlobDownloadSwift) for some regular downloading tasks. After the update, I get a compiler error "'NSError' is not convertible to 'NSError?'"from the following method from the framework:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError sessionError: NSError?) {
        let download = self.downloads[task.taskIdentifier]!
        var error: NSError? = sessionError ?? download.error

        // Handle possible HTTP errors
        if let response = task.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            // NSURLErrorDomain errors are not supposed to be reported by this delegate
            // according to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html
            // so let's ignore them as they sometimes appear there for now. (But WTF?)
            if !validateResponse(response) && (error == nil || error!.domain == NSURLErrorDomain) {
                error = NSError(domain: kTCBlobDownloadErrorDomain,
                                  code: TCBlobDownloadError.TCBlobDownloadHTTPError.rawValue,
                              userInfo: [kTCBlobDownloadErrorDescriptionKey: "Erroneous HTTP status code: \(response.statusCode)",
                                         kTCBlobDownloadErrorFailingURLKey: task.originalRequest.URL,
                                         kTCBlobDownloadErrorHTTPStatusKey: response.statusCode])
            }
        }

        // Remove reference to the download
        self.downloads.removeValueForKey(task.taskIdentifier)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            download.delegate?.download(download, didFinishWithError: error, atLocation: download.resultingURL)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow I cannot assign a `NSError`(initialized with `initWithDomain:code:userInfo`)to `error`(NSError?) anymore. What has changed in Swift 1.2? How should I fix this?

Returning a `NSError?` seems to be normal among networking related functions, especially if objC libraries were used. I'm now confused about the best way to carry an error, should I use `NSError`, `NSError?` or `NSErrorPointer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed the problem, turns out there's nothing wrong with assigning an optional value to a NSError. the `userInfo` dictionary I pass to `NSError`'s init method takes a URL from `NSURLSessionTask`'s `OriginalRequest`,which is a `NSURLRequest`. this property is now changed to `NSURL?`. I changed to `task.originalRequest.URL!` and it worked.

I guess I will continue using `NSError?` to pass down errors.

Comment: by the way, if you are trying to update to Swift 1.2, remember the compiler does not necessarily give you the right hint, look for API changes.